# Yii 2 error - Trying to get a property of non object

Tags: yii2

I was trying to search the needed information, but couldn't find any of that. Somehow, I get this error and I don't know where I'm doing a mistake.

Here is my action:

```
public function actionFilter()
{
    $filterParams = Yii::$app->request->get();
    unset($filterParams['r']);

    $model = new Sale();
    $dataProvider = $model->filterParameters($filterParams);

    return $this->render('filter', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterParams' => $filterParams,
    ]);
}
```

And here is my view:

```
'attribute' => 'sale_id',
'width' => '14%',
'value' => function (Sale $model) {
    return $model->sale->client->getClientName();
}
],  
[
    'attribute' => '',
    'value' => function (Sale $model) {
        return $model->sale->client->getClientSale();
    }
],
```

I'm getting the error on the `'value' return line`. The function `getClientName()` is in `client` model. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably there's no model linked to your main `$model`. You should check if it's set by:

```
return $model->debtor && $model->debtor->client ? $model->debtor->client->getFullName() : null;
```

AND

```
 return $model->debtor && $model->debtor->user ? $model->debtor->user->getFullName() : null;
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying `linked`? Could you evaluate your explanation? :/

Comment: It means that: 1) your foreign keys in table is empty 2) your foreign key has no data in related table 3) your relation in model is mistakenly written

Comment: Meh.. Maybe could you also explain what your if sentence here does? I cannot understand that. Thanks for your time

Comment: This `if` sentence checks if `$model->debtor` is set (is not null/false) AND if it is, it checks if `$model->debtor->client`  is set, if both are set - it will displayyour value, otherwise just `(not set)`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple:

Turn-off PHP Notice Errors in PHP.ini

error_reporting E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Answer (score -1):

In your view; just add @ before the $model to override the problem. Find an example below:

```
return @$model->sale->client->getClientName();
```